# log4j2.xmlで枝番(%i)の初期値を000にしたい

Tags: java, apache, logging

log4j2.xmlで、以下のページにある様に%iを設定することでログローテーション毎に枝番を設定できるのですが、
ここで、初期値(最初にログ出力される場合)を000にしたいです。
タグにてmin=000としても最初にログ出力されるときに枝番が振られずそのまま表示されてしまいます。
上記を実現する他の方法ありますでしょうか。
https://qiita.com/pica/items/f801c74848f748f76b58

Answer (score 0):

この[JIRAのチケット](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2403)を見ると、バージョン2.12.0以降を使用していれば、次のような書き方（`%i{03}`）でゼロ埋めの3桁はいけそうですね。

```xml
filePattern="${base}/log-%i{03}.log"
```

※私は動作検証していません。コミットの履歴を見ると、バージョンによっては`%03i`のような書き方で動作するかもしれません。書式を他の定義と合わせるため、`%03i`から`%i{03}`のような書式に変更されているようなので。